# Regex to Split String which follows ABNF form

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I do have a string which follows a particular grammar.

String could be like this :

```
String query = query1 (param1,param2), query2, query3, query4 (param1);
```

There is no common word available. All query/param can be any string which may contain characters and digits.

We need a regex to split this form in such a way that, it should return:

```
query1 (param1,param2)
query2
query3
query4 (param1)
```

Currently I have used this regex `"\\),"` Like : `query.split ("\\),");`

so it is returning following result:

```
query1 (param1,param2
query2, query3, query4 (param1
```

Do I need to correct this regex? Is it feasible to use regex to split this form of String?

Comment: Regex is not a grammar parser. It is the wrong tool for the job, *especially* not for `split()`. --- *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."*

Comment: Would you like to suggest some other way to split this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You can use this regex to achieve what you need:

```
\s?(.+?)[,;](?![\w,]+?\))
```

And here's a snippet that does the matching:

```java
String query = "query1 (param1,param2,param3), query2, query3, query4 (param1);";
String pattern = "\\s?(.+?)[,;](?![\\w,]+?\\))";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(query);

while (m.find()) {
  list.add(m.group(1));
}

System.out.println(list); // [query1 (param1,param2,param3),  query2,  query3,  query4 (param1)]
```

### Explanation

We create a capture group using the paranthesis, and tell it to end when it sees a `,` or a `;` character, but only if there's no `)` right after it (this is what the negative lookahead is for - `(?!\w+?\))`)

We also want to remove the leading whitespace so we added the `\s?` part outside of the capture group.

Comment: Is ; delimiter mandatory in the String ?

Can i use only this : String query = "query1 (param1,param2,param3), query2, query3, query4 (param1)" .. If i use without ; then it is not listing down query4 (Param1)

Comment: @SitaramP It is required because we want to check if this character appears after the capture group. An alternative would be this one: `"\\s?(.+?)(?:,|;$)(?![\\w,]+?\\))"`, notice the `"(?:,|;$)"`, it means "either a `,` character, or a `;` character **but it must appear at the end of the string**".